# Horizontal scrolling needs to stop after scrolling one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have implemented horizontal scroll as shown in this fiddle : 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/atAHh/)

What I want to do is to stop scrolling after it has scrolled 1 div and then continue from where it left after clicking the next/prev button. Right now it is continuing to scroll until it reaches end but I want to stop scrolling after 1 div. How can this be done ?

```
function startScrolling(modifier, step) {
    if (scrollHandle === 0) {
        scrollHandle = setInterval(function () {
            var newOffset = parent.scrollLeft() + (scrollStep * modifier);

            parent.scrollLeft(newOffset);
        }, 10);
    }
}

function stopScrolling() {
    clearInterval(scrollHandle);
    scrollHandle = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use animate method and inside the argument,put the new scrollLeft position you want.

Something like:

**.animate({scrollLeft:'+=200'},1000);**

The width of your div is 500,so if you put this in the code above,scrolling will stop after one div.